# Why is Common Lisp famous library Dexador not working for this HTTP POST request case? Is it a bug or did I miss something?

Tags: http, authentication, post, token, common-lisp

I am using SBCL, Emacs, Slime, and Dexador. I am also watching this course on Udemy about [Postman](https://www.udemy.com/course/postman-the-complete-guide/).

At some point, the instructor presents a POST request that uses basic authentication. It is summarized by the following picture:

[image]

The POST request is made at the address `https://simple-tool-rental-api.glitch.me/api-clients`. In addition, a message as the body in JSON format is submitted:

```json
{
    "clientName": "Postman",
    "clientEmail": "pedro@gmail.com"
}
```

As a reply, the server responds with:

```json
{
    "accessToken": "079e7bb6d3832c0d7054ae0e1146d6ed3277836fefd2e0aa9e5d7d207945e17f"
}
```

I tried doing the same using the famous library called [Dexador](https://github.com/fukamachi/dexador) and using the documentation instructions:

```
CL-USER>(dex:post "https://simple-tool-rental-api.glitch.me/api-clients"
            :content '(("clientName" . "Postman") ("clientEmail" . "pete@example.com")))
```

Unfortunately, Slime returns an error message indicating a 400 bad request:

```lisp
An HTTP request to "https://simple-tool-rental-api.glitch.me/api-clients" returned 400 bad request.

{"error":"Invalid or missing client name."}
```

Is this a bug? Did I miss something?

Comment: You say the api uses basic authentication, but you're not sending any credentials (using `:basic-auth '("username" . "password")`)

Comment: You show an address `pedro@gmail.com` and you use one in `pete`. Are you sure of the credentials? (did you try them with another tool?)

Comment: Will there be a difference between a RAW body (capture) and dex:post that uses `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: I used `pedro`and `pete` because it was necessary to have two different emails. After using one, it becomes registered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A working example:

```lisp
(dex:request "https://simple-tool-rental-api.glitch.me/api-clients"
                      :method :post 
                      :headers '(("Content-Type" . "application/json"))
                      :content "{\"clientName\":\"Postman\",
                        \"clientEmail\": \"pete@example.com\"}" 
                      :verbose t)
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
POST /api-clients HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Dexador/0.9.15 (SBCL 1.4.5.debian); Linux; 5.0.0-31-generic
Host: simple-tool-rental-api.glitch.me
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 83

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2022 12:44:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 82
Connection: keep-alive
x-powered-by: Express
etag: W/"52-egRRCktqEOIEh9dS2uY8rWUiyfY"

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
"{\"accessToken\":\"7e559ebee8ff889054346dbbd727c1bb9b9d55123fb5bd49686337e8829f8b78\"}"
201
#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 6 {1003C05373}>
#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://simple-tool-rental-api.glitch.me/api-clients>
#<CL+SSL::SSL-STREAM for #<FD-STREAM for "socket 192.168.1.53:39148, peer: 18.205.205.44:443" {10035F4C33}>>
```

I use the "pete" email because the pedro one is "already registered".
I use hand-formatted JSON to send the credentials with a `Content-Type` of `application/json`, which format I am sure about. I wanted to use a "raw" content-type as in the Postman screen capture, but wasn't sure the alist played nice with it.

I think by knowing better the example API you could sort out another content-type to use with the alist body content.